# Is antisocial behaviour a "crime"?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, police

It seems almost to be its own entity, almost like contempt of court in being neither criminal nor civil, as well as analogous to the process of being bound over for a breach of the peace.

For example it seems that one only has to give one's name and details if one is either reasonably suspected of an "offence," *or* of engaging in or having engaged in antisocial behaviour.

Comment: Its generally, I think a civil rather than criminal crime.

Comment: What is a "civil crime"?

Comment: P: It deals with an injury to an individual or other private party. Whilst criminal law deals with an injury to the public, society or state. Anti-social behaviour belongs to the first whilst murder belongs to the second.

Comment: Do you mean a civil *wrong*?

Comment: P: I mean a civil crime

Comment: @MoziburUllah In most jurisdictions that is known as a *[tort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tort)* or, sometimes, a civil wrong; not a civil crime. A "civil crime" is an oxymoron.

Comment: You need to define the specific behavior.  If I don't feel like socializing and spend a weekend alone with my dog it that considered anti-social?  Because that certainly isn't a crime.  The question is way too broad as it's worded.

Comment: As usual the down voters don't bother giving any constructive feedback strongly suggesting abuse of voting in furtherance of an ad hominem vendetta.

Comment: As usual, I did provide constructive feedback for my DV.  I can’t speak for the others.

Comment: Cheers, much appreciated. I think unfortunately you may have misunderstood the question in this instance: antisocial behaviour happens in fact to have a specific legal meaning in the UK in the context of specific legislation. It was featured in a book some time back called Unspeak and framed as a deliberate vague and nebulous sort of catch all encroachment on civil liberties etc but it is a distinct term from just the colloquial usage of the phrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not *exactly*, some actions that fall under "antisocial behaviour" **are** crimes in of themselves and they can be prosecuted in the normal manner (Of course where someone is prosecuted for those they're prosecuted for the specific crime not "antisocial behaviour")

This doesn't mean however that doing anything that's not explicitly illegal leaves the Police powerless. In the [Anti-social Behaviour, Crime and Policing Act 2014](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/12/part/1/crossheading/injunctions) there's a pretty broad definition of the term "antisocial behaviour":

> (a)conduct that has caused, or is likely to cause, harassment, alarm or distress to any person,
>
> (b)conduct capable of causing nuisance or annoyance to a person in relation to that person's occupation of residential premises, or
>
> (c)conduct capable of causing housing-related nuisance or annoyance to any person.

A constable can issue a Community Protection Notice (CPN) or the Police and select other organisations the option to apply for a civil injunction aimed at preventing the perpetrator(s) from continuing, the injunctions are ordered by Magistrates sitting in a civil capacity and the standard of proof is the civil one - i.e. "balance of probabilities" not "reasonable doubt". Violating a CPN can lead to a fine of between £100 and £2500 while violating such an injunction is considered Contempt of Court and while that still isn't a criminal offence can still see the guilty party land in jail for [up to 2 years](https://www.gov.uk/civil-injunctions-criminal-behaviour-orders).

Answer (score 4):

Antisocial behaviour refers to a variety of nuisance and criminal behavior. This includes noisy neighbours, vandalism, public drunkeness, fly tipping and street drug dealing.

The legal definition depends on where the behaviour occurs and relies on the impact of the behaviour more than the details of the behaviour:

- in a housing context it is behaviour that causes or is likely to cause nuisance or annoyance;
- in public spaces it is behaviour that causes or is likely to cause harassment, alarm or distress.

Depending on the circumstances it could be behaviour that engages civil and criminal law. For example, graffiti, fly-tipping and drug-dealing are criminal offences. However, sometimes it might be preferable to use civil or informal remedies before criminal law.

The [Anti-social Behaviour, Crime and Policing Act 2014](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/12/contents) provides for powers to prevent and punish antisocial behaviour. These include injunctions and civil orders, the breach of which may be a contempt of court or criminal offence in itself.

The [House of Commons Library Briefing Paper, Tackling anti-social behaviour](https://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/CBP-7270/CBP-7270.pdf), seems a comprehensive review of how antisocial behaviour is defined, who is responsible for tackling it, the legislation and the use of the powers.